# bitcoin-core commands RPC syntax probelm

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I installed bitcoin-core on Ubuntu 19 by snap.
But its primary commands are different than usual,even with official bitcoin-core docs.
My commands starts with **bitcoin-core.cli** instead of **bitcoind** or **bitcoin.cli**.
 
another example :
**bitcoind getinfo** and not    **bitcoin-core.cli getinfo**

I'd like to change it if possible to the official commands syntax

Comment: Horrible deception

Answer (score -2):

You can try renaming the bin file...

Example :

if you're running linux, you can check where the binary file is at through terminal and using 'which' command:

```
which {command name}

$ which bitcoin-core.cli
```

It returns the {file path}/{bin file}

An example of the result, change this accordingly /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-core.cli . You can rename it by using **mv** command or copy it using **cp** into the same directory

using mv

```
mv /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-core.cli /usr/local/bin/bitcoind
```

or cp

```
cp /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-core.cli /usr/local/bin/bitcoind
```